# How to easily get year and month with leading zero in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a snapshot date in the following format: 2021-06-28 and I would like to have it like that: 202106. So the first four digits is year and next two is the month with leading zero. I tried this code:

```
concat(extract(year from snapshot_date), extract(month from snapshot_date))
```

but I have in return: 20216, without leading zero. How can I easily get it without CASE statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [format_date](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date):

```
select format_date("%Y%m", snapshot_date) 
from mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming snapshot_date is of date data type - you can use recently introduced [Format clause for CAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#formatting_syntax) as in below example

```
select cast(snapshot_date as string format 'YYYYMM')
from `project.dataset.table`
```

Answer (score 0):

if "snapshot_date" is in date format, then this should work

```
select to_char(snapshot_date, 'yyyymm') from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

As a note, you can return the value as a number and just use multiplication:

```
(extract(year from snapshot_date) * 100 + extract(month from snapshot_date)) as yyyymm
```